# Using the adverb "again" after the idiom "repeating oneself"

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, adverbs

I was wondering whether it would sound superfluous if I add the adverb "again" to the end of the sentence:

> **Steve Rogers:** Well, what are we gonna do now? 
>   **Tony Stark:** You know what, give me a break, Steve. I just got hit in the head with a Hulk. 
>   **Scott Lang:** You said that we had one shot. This! This was our shot. We shot it, it's shot! Six stones or nothing! Six stones or nothing. 
>   **Tony Stark:** You're repeating yourself **'again'**. [[Source]](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/characters/nm0748620)

Comment: It sounds like tautology (saying the same thing in two different ways, like _retreat back_), but if Tony had earlier accused Scott of repeating himself, he could legitimately use 'again'.

Comment: It could also be literal: *I said "Jump." One minute later, I repeated myself. Two minutes after that, I repeated myself **again**. By the end of the hour, I had repeated myself a total of 59 times.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "again" at the end emphasises the repetitiveness (repetition).

other examples:
- "over and over and over ... again" (both the repeated use of over and the addition of again)
- "forever and ever. Amen" (prayer)